# Generate large prime number with specified last digits

Tags: c#, java, algorithm, primes

Was wondering how is it possible to generate 512 bit (155 decimal digits) prime number, last five decimal digits of which are specified/fixed (eg. ***28071) ??

The principles of generating simple primes without any specifications are quite understandable, but my case goes further.

Any hints for, at least, where should I start?

Java or C# is preferable.

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds difficult, if not impossible without bruteforcing through the 155 digit primes and checking each one. Interesting question though :P

Comment: Also, this question may be more suited for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Don't bruteforce through primes, bruteforce through numbers fulfilling the criterion and check them for primes. That shouldn't be that slow since the prime density is rather high.

Comment: @thejh: you can't sieve up to 10^155.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the contribution! Problem solved for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess the only way would be to first generate a random number of 150 decimal digits, then append the 28071 behind it by doing `number = randomnumber * 100000 + 28071` then just brute force it out with something like

```
while (!IsPrime(number))
    number += 100000;
```

Of course this could take awhile to compute ;-)

Comment: Wouldn't be that slow since you only need to try a few hundred times.

Comment: @CodeInChaos It's not that it only needs a few check's it's that the IsPrime check on such a large number is going to take a really long time.

Comment: It's slow if IsPrime checks for exactly prime number. to phase test is better.

Comment: I estimated that time as below 100ms for the common case(non prime) And if that test succeeds you can do a slow but thorough test.

Comment: Well, thats what i did. Brute forced the number = randomnumber * 100000 + 28071 with isProbablePrime. Was quite fast.

Answer (score 7):

Did you try just generating such numbers and checking them? I would expect that to be acceptably fast. The prime density decreases only as the logarithm of the number, so I'd expect you to try a few hundred numbers until you hit a prime. `ln(2^512) = 354` so about one number in 350 will be prime.

> Roughly speaking, the prime number theorem states that if a random number nearby some large number N is selected, the chance of it being prime is about 1 / ln(N), where ln(N) denotes the natural logarithm of N. For example, near N = 10,000, about one in nine numbers is prime, whereas near N = 1,000,000,000, only one in every 21 numbers is prime. In other words, the average gap between prime numbers near N is roughly ln(N)

*(from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem)*

You just need to take care that a number exists for your final digits. But I think that's as easy as checking that the last digit isn't divisible by 2 or 5 (i.e. it is 1, 3, 7 or 9).

According to [this performance data](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2128845&tstart=0) you can do about 2000 ModPow operations on 512 bit data per second, and since a simple prime-test is checking `2^(p-1) mod p=1` which is one ModPow operation, you should be able to generate several primes with your properties per second.

So you could do (pseudocode):

```
BigInteger FindPrimeCandidate(int lastDigits)
{
    BigInteger i=Random512BitInt;
    int remainder = i % 100000;
    int increment = lastDigits-remainder;
    i += increment;
    BigInteger test = BigInteger.ModPow(2, i - 1, i);
    if(test == 1)
      return i;
    else
      return null;
}
```

And do more extensive prime checks on the result of that function.

Answer (score 3):

As @Doggot said, but start from least possible 150 digit number which ends with 28071, means 100000....0028071, now add it up with 100000 each time and for testing primarily use miller rabin like the code I provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236673/sample-code-for-fast-primality-testing-in-c/4236870#4236870), It needs some customization. If the return value is true, check it for exact primarily.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a sieve which contains only numbers satisfying your special condition to filter out numbers divisible by small primes.

For each small prime `p` you need to find the correct starting point and step by taking into account that only each 100000th number is present in the sieve.

For the numbers that survive the sieve you can use [`BigInteger.isProbablePrime()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#isProbablePrime(int)) to check whether it is prime with sufficient probability.

Answer (score 2):

Let ABCDE be the five digits number in base ten, which you are considering. Based on [Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions), if ABCDE and 100000 are coprime, then there are infinitely many primes of the form 100000*k+ABCDE. Since you are looking for prime numbers, neither 2 nor 5 would divide ABCDE anyway, thus ABCDE and 100000 are coprime. So there are **infinitely** many primes of the form you are considering.

Comment: Yes, but the first `k` that results in a prime may be arbitrarily large. How large? Depends on ABCDE. So you need to do a brute-force search of `k` and the usual expensive primality test for each candidate `k`.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend one of the [standard methods for generating large primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_primes) by adding an extra constraint, i.e. that the last 5 decimal digits must be correct. Naively, you can just add this as an extra test but it will increase the time to find a suitable prime by 10^5.

Not-so-naively: generate a random 512-bit number then set sufficient low-order bits so that the decimal representation ends with the required sequence. Then continue with the normal primality tests.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider brute-force. Take a look at this very interesting text called "The prime number lottery":

- http://plus.maths.org/content/prime-number-lottery

Given the last entry in the last table, there are ~2.79*10^14 primes less then 10^16. Thus, approximately every 35th number is a prime in that range.

EDIT: See the comment by CodeInChaos - if you just walk a few thousand 512bit numbers with last 5 digits fixed, you'll find one quickly.

Comment: You can just only try the numbers with the correct end digits. And for 512 bit numbers every 350th and not 35th number is a prime.

Comment: True, thanks for the correction and the 512bit info, I'll edit!

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote the brute-force algorithm from the `int` world to the `BigDecimal` one with the help of the `BigSquareRoot` class from http://www.merriampark.com/bigsqrt.htm. (Note that from 1 to 1000 there is said to be exactly 168 primes.)

Sorry, but if you put there your range, i.e. <10<sup>154</sup>; 10<sup>155</sup>-1>, you can let your computer work and when you have retired, you may have the result... it is damn slow!

However, you can somehow find at least a part of this useful in combination with the other answers in this thread.

```
package edu.eli.test.primes;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class PrimeNumbersGenerator {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
//    BigDecimal lowerLimit = BigDecimal.valueOf(10).pow(154); /* 155 digits */
//    BigDecimal upperLimit = BigDecimal.valueOf(10).pow(155).subtract(BigDecimal.ONE);

    BigDecimal lowerLimit = BigDecimal.ONE;
    BigDecimal upperLimit = new BigDecimal("1000");

    BigDecimal prime = lowerLimit;
    int i = 1;

    /* http://www.merriampark.com/bigsqrt.htm */
    BigSquareRoot bsr = new BigSquareRoot();
    upperLimit = upperLimit.add(BigDecimal.ONE);
    while (prime.compareTo(upperLimit) == -1) {

      bsr.setScale(0);
      BigDecimal roundedSqrt = bsr.get(prime);

      boolean isPrimeNumber = false;
      BigDecimal upper = roundedSqrt;
      while (upper.compareTo(BigDecimal.ONE) == 1) {

        BigDecimal div = prime.remainder(upper);
        if ((prime.compareTo(upper) != 0) && (div.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0)) {
          isPrimeNumber = false;
          break;
        } else if (!isPrimeNumber) {
          isPrimeNumber = true;
        }

        upper = upper.subtract(BigDecimal.ONE);
      }

      if (isPrimeNumber) {
        System.out.println("\n" + i + " -> " + prime + " is a prime!");
        i++;
      } else {
        System.out.print(".");
      }
      prime = prime.add(BigDecimal.ONE);
    }
  }

}
```