# 16-digit timestamp with PHPs date() function

Tags: php, xml, timestamp

How can I use the following 16-digit timestamp (from an XML file) with PHP's `date()` function?

```
1295076698126000  // 15-01-2011 08:31:38.126
1286697695521000  // 10-10-2010 10:01:35.521
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those timestamps are in microseconds. However, since PHP uses integers for timestamps in seconds with `date()`, you won't be able to obtain the microsecond value. You're still able to print the rest of the date by dividing the timestamp by a million (1 million microseconds = 1 second), and passing the quotient to `date()`:

```
// "u" will always be printed as 000000 regardless of actual microseconds
echo date('d-m-Y H:i:s.u', 1295076698126000 / 1000000);
```

**EDIT:** Hacky, but you can perform manual arithmetic to get the milliseconds and output it separately as a workaround, like this:

```
$xml_timestamp = 1295076698126000;
$seconds = $xml_timestamp / 1000000;
$microseconds = $seconds - floor($seconds);
$seconds = floor($seconds);

// 1 millisecond = 1000 microseconds
// Milliseconds, because your desired output is 3 decimal places long, not 6
$milliseconds = round($microseconds * 1000);

$format = 'd-m-Y H:i:s.' . sprintf('%03d', $milliseconds);
echo date($format, $seconds);
```

For reusability the `DateTime` class is a good option. Or, a custom function:

```
function date_milliseconds($format, $timestamp = NULL) {
    $seconds = ($timestamp === NULL) ? microtime(true) : $timestamp / 1000000;
    $microseconds = $seconds - floor($seconds);
    $seconds = floor($seconds);
    $milliseconds = round($microseconds * 1000);

    $format = preg_replace('/(?<!\\\\)u/', sprintf('%03d', $milliseconds), $format);
    return date($format, $seconds);
}

echo date_milliseconds('d-m-T H:i:s.u', floatval($xml_timestamp));
```

Comment: Note that you *can* use "u" with the `DateTime` object, as per Edward Rudd's comment on the `date()` manual page: http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#93891  But this isn't actually very useful, since I can't see a simple way to *set* a microsecond timestamp (`setTimestamp()` seems to cast the input to int).

Comment: Can you make the code dynamic? `echo $timestamp*1` always gives the same number (2147483647), see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573692/is-the-size-of-an-array-constrained-by-the-upper-limit-of-int-2147483647

Comment: @Kristoffer: What version of PHP are you on? PHP turns `$timestamp` into a float for me when it exceeds the 32-bit signed int limit.

Comment: Current version v5.3.5 - with SimpleXML to parse the XML.

Comment: If you `var_dump()` the timestamps immediately after obtaining them with SimpleXML what do you get?

Comment: And: `echo var_dump($timestamp*1);` outputs an integer (example: $timestamp = 1286911435434000) - please notice this may be caused by SimpleXML.

Comment: Well, whether it's `int(1286911435434000)` or `float(1286911435434000)`, it looks like it's not overflowing. If you can dump it from SimpleXML without affecting its numeric value you should be able to assign it to a new variable, then pass it to `date_milliseconds()` (unfortunately I can't test the SimpleXML part right now).