# C# Long Substring function

Tags: c#, .net, string, substring

I have a string that "may" be longer than any simple int boundaries.

Currently, the string.substring function takes only int parameters as index and length which is not enough for me since i need long for the parameter value types.

Do you know any implementation of long substring function?

Or what do you recommend I do to solve this possible finding substring problem with very long string?

Thank you.

Comment: A string that long (>2G chars) would take up >4GB memory. Are you sure that the substring function is going to be your only problem?

Comment: How long is the string? And what about the substring? You probably don't want to load the entire string into memory at once, but use a file stream to read portions of the file while searching for the substring?

Comment: The possible string matching process will probably only take place on memory and amount of available memory for the machine is supposedly very large. The strings that this operation will work on is, whole string is around 10G chars and substring is 1000 chars or so. I agree that any string matching operation on that large strings would be algorithmically idiotic in addition to resource requirements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have a string that "may" be longer than any simple int boundaries.

No, in .NET you won't have that problem. The `System.String` class itself uses `Int32` indexing and Length properties everywhere.

Maybe you will have a (char) array that's over 2GB but that is taken care of, you can use 'long` indexing.

Related question: [What is the maximum possible length of a .NET string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140468/)

Comment: I like the comment _This is one of those situations where "If you have to ask, you're probably doing something wrong."_

Comment: not even arrays... See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573692/is-the-size-of-an-array-constrained-by-the-upper-limit-of-int-2147483647/573701#573701 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087982/single-objects-still-limited-to-2-gb-in-size-in-clr-4-0/1088044#1088044

Comment: @xanatos: You're right, I was thinking about that LongLength property but that's not indexing.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer in the link Henk provides states, you cannot create an object of size greater than 2GB in .NET ([64-bit also has this restriction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241064%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)).

**Therefore you can't have a string that big no matter what.** You will need to use some sort of streaming algorithm to find and isolate the data you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

As Henk Holterman said System.String uses int32 ....

But if needed to, use unsigned int which can go to 4.300 million:
try uint.

```
uint stringLength =  4,294,967,295
```

though it doesnt go that much higher than the normal int

int -> -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
uint -> 0 to 4,294,967,295

Answer (score 0):

Also, conventional substring algorithms might not work well on that scale (actually I do not know how .Substring works). You might want to take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm).