# Seeking and writing files bigger than 2GB in C#

Tags: c#, filestream

In C#, the `FileStream`'s methods Read/Write/Seek take `integer` in parameter. In a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654298/filestream-read-write-methods-limitation) , I have seen a good solution to read/write files that are bigger than the virtual memory allocated to a process.

This solution works if you want to write the data from the beginning to the end. But in my case, the chunks of data I am receiving are in no particular order.

I have a code that works for files smaller than 2GB :

```
private void WriteChunk(byte[] data, int position, int chunkSize, int count, string path)
    {

        FileStream destination = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(destination);
        writer.Seek((int) (position*chunkSize), SeekOrigin.Begin);
        writer.Write(data, 0, count);
        writer.Close();
    }
```

Is there a way I can seek and write my chunks in files bigger than 2GB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use int, use long. Seek takes a long.

You need to use long everywhere though and not just cast to int somewhere.

Comment: Thanks! I saw that BinaryWriter has no overload to seek with a long, but FileStream has.

Comment: MSDN docs show offset parameter of BinaryWriter.Seek as an int. Double checked in VS2010 and BinaryWriter.Seek shows first paramter as int with no overloads. How is it going to take a long then ?

Comment: You need to seek the FileStream before opening the BinaryReader.

Answer (score 2):

```
writer.Seek((long)position*chunkSize, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Comment: The use the filestream driectly, foo!

Comment: int and long has maximum value of 2g, so I don't understamd what's the different?

Comment: @Eitan: long is 8 bytes in C#