# Types for large numbers

Tags: c#, math, largenumber

I am working on an app that will need to handle very large numbers.

I checked out a few available LargeNumber classes and have found a few that I am happy with. I have a class for large integers and for large floating point numbers.

Since some of the numbers will be small and some large the question is whether it is worth checking the length of the number and if it is small use a regular C# int or double and if is is large use the other classes I have or if I am already using the Large Integer and Large Float classes I should just stick with them even for smaller numbers.

My consideration is purely performance. Will I save enough time on the math for the smaller numbers that it would be worthwhile to check each number after is is put in.

Comment: Please see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494923/numbers-that-exceeds-basic-types-in-c).

Comment: Which classes are you using for larger numbers?

Comment: I am playing with a few.

Microsoft.FSharp.Math.BigInt
Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Common.BigInteger
http://www.codeproject.com/csharp/biginteger.asp
IntX

for decimals i am using
w3b.sine
Microsoft.FSharp.Math.BigNum

I am going to do some benchmarks on all of them and see what i get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really hard to tell - Depends on your 3rd party libraries :)

Best bet would be to use the System.Diagnostics.StopWatch class, do a gazzillion different calculations, time them and compare the results, I guess ..

[EDIT] - About the benchmarks, I'd do a series of benchmarks your largeInt-type to do the calculations on regular 32/64 bits numbers, and a series checking if the number can fit in the regular Int32/Int64 types (which they should), "downcasting" them to these types, and then run the same calculations using these types. From your question, this sounds like what you'll be doing if the built-in types are faster..

If your application is targetted for more people than yourself, try to run them on different machines (single core, multicore, 32bit, 64bit platforms), and if the platform seems to have a large impact in the time the calculations take, use some sort of strategy-pattern to do the calculations differently on different machines.

Good luck :)

Comment: @Sruly - those that duplicate the type of maths your application needs ;-p

Answer (score 2):

I would expect that a decent large numbers library would be able to do this optimization on it's own...

Answer (score 2):

I would say yes, the check will more than pay for itself, as long as you have enough values within the regular range.

The logic is simple: an integer addition is one assembly instruction. Combined with a comparison, that's three or four instructions. Any software implementation of such operation will most probably be much slower.

Optimally, this check should be done in the LargeNumber libraries themselves. If they don't do it, you may need  a wrapper to avoid having checks all over the place. But then you need to think of the additional cost of the wrapper as well.

Answer (score 0):

Worked in a project where the same fields needed to handle very large numbers and at the same time handels precision for very small numbers.
The ended up with storing to fields (mantissa and exponent) for every number of such kind.
We made a class for mantissa/exponent calculations and it performed well.