# How to get completely accurate values in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Huge Integer JavaScript Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964139/huge-integer-javascript-library)

Suppose I want the exact value for **2^1000**. How am I supposed to get the *entire* value? Maybe storing it in a string every time the multiplication is done, but it will still eventually go over 10 digits! Is there any way, or does ECMAScript just not support this?

Comment: You can't. Javascript doesn't support 1000 bit integers. You're gonna have to invent your own system for storing and working with large numbers.

Comment: Oh. Alright. Any great insights from anyone as to how I could do something like this?

Comment: See Quentin's comment, or search on "big int javascript library".

Comment: Sounds like someone is missing the point of Project Euler - http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=16

Comment: Hahahaha, I am trying Project Euler, but I am not asking for a direct solution, just any ideas. I am not going to use the BigInt library to solve the problem directly. :D. Glad to see more Euler people on here.

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377361/sum-of-the-digits-of-the-number-21000 but in terms of the problem would be a better fit for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.pow(2,1000)
```

returns

```
1.0715086071862673e+301
```

how accurate do you need this to be?

Comment: I need all the digits. I know it's a stretch, but is it possible?