# Multiplying floats gives infinite values

Tags: c++, multiplication

I tried a lot of methods:

```
float a = 1234.34;
float b = 1234.52;
float r = a * b;
cout << r << endl;
float c = 1234.34 * 1234.52;
cout << c << endl;

cout << 1234.34 * 1234.52 << endl;
cout << (float)(1234.34 * 1234.52) << endl;
```

And all of these seem to be giving an infinite values..

```
1.52382e+006
1.52382e+006
1.52382e+006
1.52382e+006
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: None of those seem to be giving an infinite values [sic]. Perhaps you're simply not familiar with the [E notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation)

Comment: That's not an infinite value. It's the floating-point representation of the product you're multiplying. Your code is working fine.

Comment: Your definition of infinite seems quite small. You are multiplying two numbers that are about 1,000 times each other. The answer should be around 1,000,000. 1.52382e6 is the same as 1.52382*10^6, which is 1.5 million. Seems like the computer works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301547/turn-off-scientific-notation-on-float

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number in the result is nowhere close to approaching infinity.

The result is simply C++ showing the value in scientific notation.

Please check [How to avoid scientific notation for large numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265258/how-to-avoid-scientific-notation-for-large-numbers).

Answer (score 3):

The values are not infinite, they're only in scientific notation.

`1.52382e+006` evaluates to `1.52382 * (10)^6`.

You may want to use `doubles`, and set the precision for the `ostream`:

```
#include <limits>    // std::numeric_limits
#include <iostream>  // std::cout

int main() {
  double f = 3.141592;

  std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10);
  std::cout << std::fixed;
  std::cout << f;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, how can I get the value of multiplication the floats in numbers (normal)?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is correct. 1.52382e+006 is same as 1.52382 * 10<sup>6</sup>

If you don't want the output in E format, use [std::fixed](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    float a = 1234.34;
    float b = 1234.52;
    float r = a * b;
    cout << std::fixed << r << endl;
    float c = 1234.34 * 1234.52;
    cout << std::fixed << c << endl;

    cout << std::fixed << 1234.34 * 1234.52 << endl;
    cout << std::fixed << (float)(1234.34 * 1234.52) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This code outputs the following

> 1523817.375000
>   1523817.375000
>   1523817.416800
>   1523817.375000

Answer (score 1):

What you get is the scientific notation of your results, 1523817.4168, which in in scientific notation is 1.52382E+6, where the E stands for "10^", meaning 1.52382 * 10 ^ 6, you can look it up.

Answer (score 1):

That is just scientific notation. It does not signify infinity.